# What's wrong with the KTOR file upload example?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

Here's the code from the example [on this page](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#upload_file).

```
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.features.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.client.request.forms.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.android.*

val response: HttpResponse = client.submitFormWithBinaryData(
    url = "http://localhost:8080/upload",
    formData = formData {
        append("description", "Ktor logo")
        append("image", File("ktor_logo.png").readBytes(), Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=ktor_logo.png")
        })
    }
)
```

When I paste this code into Android studio I get the following error.

```
Function invocation 'formData(...)' expected
```

It's odd that official example code would fail like this, so did I do something wrong? What do I need to do to correct this problem?

Additional info...

If I remove one of the 'formData' elements it will compile, but I'm guessing won't do what I think it should do because it's not setting a property.

```
    formData {
        append("bitmapName", "image.png")
```

Comment: did you try the sample project: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/main/codeSnippets/snippets/client-upload-file/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt paying attension to imports

Comment: Could you please share the import statements for the code above?

Comment: I added all my imports above. It's not recognizing the 'formData' on the left of the equals sign as a property, but it should correct?

Comment: The `formData` is the name of a parameter from `submitFormWithBinaryData` function. Unfortunately, I still cannot reproduce your problem on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Based on something you said it caused me to suspect something else (spurious punctuation) on my part and that cleared things up. Please take a look at my follow-on question here if you can - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041539/how-to-upload-a-single-bitmap-image-using-ktor